# Reverse order row in list with R

Tags: r, list, matrix

Sample data:

```
list.data <- list(matrix(seq(1,30,2),5,3),matrix(seq(1,10,2),5,2))

NumOnly <- lapply(list.data, function(x) x[,2:ncol(x), drop = FALSE])
```

Transpose matrix

```
TranData <- lapply(NumOnly, function(x) t(x))
```

Reverse/flip the order

```
DataModel <- lapply(TranData, function(x) ifelse(nrow(x)==1,x,apply(x, 2, rev)))
head(DataModel)
```

How to reverse row order for matrix with `row>1` and with `row==1` leave as initially.

The above `DataModel` output somehow gives only first entries...

I would like to get:

```
   [[1]]
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  21   23   25   27   29
[2,]  11   13   15   17   19

   [[2]]
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `rev` within `[`, like this:

```
> lapply(TranData, function(x) x[rev(sequence(nrow(x))), , drop = FALSE])
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   21   23   25   27   29
[2,]   11   13   15   17   19

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
```